# How to deal with none letter keyboard input errors in python guizero/tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, chatbot, keyboard-events, guizero

When I press tab it selects all of the text in the input box unless I set the input box multiline to  true but it ends up giving the first post a strange format. I would like tab key to act like it normally does in any other program. I am also getting errors when I press **Shift** or **Caps lock** in the shell
based on whatever the first key input "***if***" statement is. Both **Shift** and **Caps lock** still end up making the text display properly.

I have tried adding an if statement to avoid tab key errors but it doesn't seem to work. I tried using pass and just a normal print statement.

What I'm using.

- Python 3.7.9
- [Thonny](https://thonny.org/) IDE 3.3.4
- [Guizero](https://lawsie.github.io/guizero/) based on tkinter.
- [ASCII table key numbers](https://theasciicode.com.ar/)

**Error I'm getting**

> **if ord(e.key) == 9: #tab key
> TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 0 found**

```
from guizero import *

app = App(bg='#121212',title='Virtual assistant',width=500,height=500)
box=Box(app,width='fill',height=420)
box.bg='light gray'
Spacer_box=Box(box,width='fill',height=5,align='top')
userName='Test Username: '

#A is set as the default text value to test if posting into the box works
#Setting multiline to true changes the first post format but allows for the tab key to work properly 
input_box = TextBox(app,text='A',width='fill',multiline=False,align="left")
input_box.text_size=15
input_box.bg='darkgray'
input_box.text_color='black'
input_box.tk.config(highlightthickness=5,highlightcolor="black")


def key_pressed(e):
    
    #stop tab key from highlighting text only when input_box multiline is set to true
    #in the input_box above
    if ord(e.key) == 9: #Tab key
        print('Tab pressed')
        
    elif ord(e.key) == 13:#Enter key
        #Checks if input box is blank or only white space. 
        if input_box.value.isspace() or len(input_box.value)==0:
            print('Empty')
            input_box.clear()
        
        else:#User's output.
            Textbox=Box(box,width='fill', align='top')
            Usernamers=Text(Textbox, text=userName,align='left')
            Usernamers.tk.config(font=("Impact", 14))
            User_Outputted_Text = Text(Textbox, text=input_box.value,size=15,align='left')
            print('Contains text')
            input_box.clear()
            #Test responce to user
            if User_Outputted_Text.value.lower()=='hi':
                Reply_box=Box(box,width='fill',align='top')
                Digital_AssistantName=Text(Reply_box,text='AI\'s name:',align='left')
                Digital_AssistantName.tk.config(font=("Impact", 14))
                Reply_text = Text(Reply_box,text='Hello, whats up?',size=15,align='left')

            

input_box.when_key_pressed = key_pressed        

app.display()
```

Comment: Try adding `if e.key == "": return None` at the start of the `key_pressed` function

Comment: Tab still does not work right unless multiline is on.

Comment: Do you know what widgets `guizero` is using behind the scenes? Is it a `tkinter.Entry` or `tkinter.Text`?

Comment: Input box is Entry and text just says its tkinter.Label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this at the beginning of `key_pressed` function will eliminate the error when <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>/<kbd>Shift</kbd> or any key that returns an empty string is pressed.

```py
if e.key=='':
    return
```

The following has worked in preventing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key from selecting the text

```py
if ord(e.key) == 9: #Tab key
    print('Tab pressed')
    input_box.append(' '*4)
    input_box.disable()
    input_box.after(1,input_box.enable)
```

Basically I have disabled the widget followed by enabling it after `1` millisecond.

**UPDATE**

Another approach could be to bind the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to the `Entry` widget used internally (which can be accessed by using the `tk` property as stated in the [docs](https://lawsie.github.io/guizero/textbox/)). I would recommend this approach over the previous, also, because the `append` method adds the text at the end, there is no built in method to insert the text at the current location, so you would ultimately end up using the `insert` method of `tkinter.Entry` with the index as `'insert'`.

```py
def select_none(event):
    input_box.tk.insert('insert',' '*4)
    return 'break'

input_box.tk.bind('<Tab>',select_none)
```

Using `return 'break'` at the end of the function prevents other event handlers from being executed.

Comment: Does that mean that `guizero.TextBox` is the equivalent to `tkinter.Text`?

Comment: Also instead of `" "*4` you can use `"\t"`. Sometimes that is better but sometimes it isn't.

Comment: @TheLizzard `guizero.TextBox.tk` is equivalent to `tkinter.Entry`

Comment: It uses `Entry` when multiline is false, I don't see why my answer *wouldn't work* it would be great if you could explain and try it yourself first.

Comment: The first answer for tab does not full work. You can't go back and insert the tab space into text you have already written. Tk approach works perfectly

Comment: @PurpleLlama yes I realized that and updated the answer

Comment: I was wrong saying that the second approach wouldn't work because I thought that `tkinter.Entry` didn't support marks (line `"insert"`) but apparently it does. I usually use `tkinter.Text` as it has more functionality.